# Upload Image after Capture - Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, image-uploading, firebase-storage

what I'm trying to do is capture an image and view it in the image view and store it to the firebase storage.

My Code:

```
public class WaterConsumptionPage extends Fragment {

private ImageView imageView;
private Button capture, upload;
static final int CAM_REQUEST = 1;
private StorageReference mStorageRef;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference dbRef;
private ProgressDialog mProgress;
private Bitmap photo;
private FirebaseUser user;
private Uri uri;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.water_consumption_page, container, false);

    mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    imageView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.water_image);
    capture = rootView.findViewById(R.id.water_capture);
    upload = rootView.findViewById(R.id.water_upload);

    upload.setEnabled(false);

    capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cam_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if(cam_intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null){
                startActivityForResult(cam_intent, CAM_REQUEST);
            }
        }
    });

    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mProgress.setMessage("Uploading Image...");
            mProgress.show();

            StorageReference filepath = mStorageRef.child("Photos").child(user.getUid()).child("Water").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    mProgress.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Upload Finished...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), WaterConsumption.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    mProgress.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Upload has stopped.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == CAM_REQUEST && data != null){
        upload.setEnabled(true);
        uri = data.getData();
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);

    }
}
```

Error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.akoni.conread, PID: 13901
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getLastPathSegment()' on a null object reference
>                         at com.example.akoni.conread.WaterConsumptionPage$2.onClick(WaterConsumptionPage.java:87)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5265)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21534)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)

I also tried putting this code below inside in the **onActivityResult()** to test if I can save image, but I still got an another error(below).

```
StorageReference filepath = mStorageRef.child("Photos").child(user.getUid()).child("Water").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
               mProgress.dismiss();
               Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Upload Finished...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), WaterConsumption.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
              @Override
              public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                  mProgress.dismiss();
                  Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Upload has stopped.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
});
```

Error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.akoni.conread, PID: 14526
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.akoni.conread/com.example.akoni.conread.TabMenu}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getLastPathSegment()' on a null object reference
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3929)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3972)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1537)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getLastPathSegment()' on a null object reference
>                         at com.example.akoni.conread.WaterConsumptionPage.onActivityResult(WaterConsumptionPage.java:120)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:151)
>                         at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6502)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3925)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3972) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1537) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)

I want to **capture the image and view it to the ImageView first** and click `upload` to save the image to the firebase.

Comment: You should tackle your problems one at a time instead of dumping a lot of errors from the same code. Remove the code related to Firebase storage and make sure you first manage to save the photo(if you want to upload the full image). You have an official tutorial on how to handle this here https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html . After you manage to solve this part edit your question and add the updated code  and then add the Firebase code and any issue you face with uploading.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove this line of code:

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Because I think this line will cause that the data.getIntent() is returning nothing.

You should also check the `resultCode` if that is OK.
Here is an example:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAM_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       Uri uri = data.getData();
    } 
  }
```